# Sequelize: Don't Save Migration / Seeder Record

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, database-migration

I'm debugging a migration, and I want to prevent MySQL from saving a migration row in the db when the migration succeeds.

In PHP, I use the method setSaveCompletionRecord(false).

Does Sequelize have an equivalent other than `db:migrate:undo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured out a good workaround for this.  Great for debugging.

At the end of the `up` function, just throw an error.  Result: sequelize doesn't finish running the migration, and thus does not add it to the 'completed migrations' table in your db.

Example: 
`throw new Error('dont mark complete');`

Answer (score 2):

You can update the config/config.js file with keys `migrationStorage` and `seederStorage`. And set these to `none`.

With these changes, Sequelize will not store  migrations in the DB.
Be advised, with this there would be no track of the migrations.

Also undoing the migrations won't be possible either.

Comment: Hmm.. This did not work for me, but it may be that my configuration is different than yours.  I also tried changing it in ./.sequelizerc, but then got an error when I tried to run the migrations.